# NullPointerException where send mail using JavaMail API

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, jakarta-mail

I Getting `NulllPointerException` error where i click on button for send mail.

I tried many solution like debugging, check all defined variables than not providing null.

Here i have used JavaMail Library for send Mail.
You can get it this source code from here:

https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary

Here are the Source Code

### Java File

```
package com.example.piyush_society_demo;

import com.kristijandraca.backgroundmaillibrary.BackgroundMail;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Add_Vendor_New_Activity extends Activity{
Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_vendor_activity);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.setTitle("Add vender");
    
        
        Button btn_vendor_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_vendor_add);

        btn_vendor_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                send_email(
                        "Thank you for Register with Us",
                        "Hello Sir, \n\n You are successfully registered with Us.",
                        "abc@gmail.com");

            }
        });

    }

    public void send_email(String msg, String body, String email) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BackgroundMail bm = new BackgroundMail(context);
        bm.setGmailUserName("Gmail Username");
        // "DoE/GTiYpX5sz5zmTFuoHg==" is crypted "password"
        bm.setGmailPassword("Gmail Password");
        // bm.setGmailPassword(Utils.encryptIt("chhavi2014"));
        // bm.setGmailPassword(Utils.decryptIt("mygmailaccount5"));
        bm.setMailTo(email);
        bm.setFormSubject(msg);
        bm.setFormBody(body);

        bm.setSendingMessage("Loading...");
        bm.setSendingMessageSuccess("Your message was sent successfully.");
        bm.setProcessVisibility(false);
                //bm.setAttachment(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.pathSeparator+"somefile.t    xt");
        bm.send();

    }


}
```

Gmail id changed.

Here are the Logcat

```
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at com.kristijandraca.backgroundmaillibrary.Utils.isNetworkAvailable(Utils.java:22)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at com.kristijandraca.backgroundmaillibrary.BackgroundMail.send(BackgroundMail.java:84)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at com.example.piyush_society_demo.Add_Vendor_New_Activity.send_email(Add_Vendor_New_Activity.java:58)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at com.example.piyush_society_demo.Add_Vendor_New_Activity$1.onClick(Add_Vendor_New_Activity.java:32)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-14 07:30:11.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please provide me solution .

Comment: @saeed thank you so much for correct my question.. and make it more understable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing your `BackgroundMail` object with a `null` `context` at

```
BackgroundMail bm = new BackgroundMail(context);
```

The `context` member variable was never initialized. This `null`context is then passed from the `BackgroundMail#send()` method to

```
Utils.isNetworkAvailable(mContext);
```

which then finally throws the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @saeed thank you for correcting and clear my question more
& Ravi Your answer is right...

Comment: @user2940072, for Saeed to receive your msg, you need to post your comment under your question. Since, you've posted it here only I get the notification. Welcome to SO! You'll learn all this in no time :)

Comment: Well i am not more familiar with Stackoverflow use  so sorry for that.. Thank Yo.. for Accurate and fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

In new BackgroundMail(context); context is null

Try `BackgroundMail bm = new BackgroundMail(getApplicationContext);` or `BackgroundMail bm = new BackgroundMail(this);`

Also you can fix it if you init context in onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.add_vendor_activity);
context = getApplicationContext();
```